# Finding out isMemberOf equivalent with Objc run-time Class type

Tags: objective-c

When I have a reference to Objc run-time's Class type, how can I find out if this class refers to an NSObject?

```
Class aClass = [NSArray class];
Class aSuperClass = class_getSuperclass(aClass); // Points to NSObject

// What's the best way to test at runtime whether aSuperClass is pointing 
// to an NSObject type?

BOOL isNSObjectClass = [aSuperClass isMemberOfClass:[NSObject class]]; // This returns NO
```

Comment: I think you may be interested in `isKindOfClass:` (more typical) and `isMemberOfClass:` (more specific, and not always a good idea). So you might do `[object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`. This doesn't address your question directly, but _might_ be closer to what you actually want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing classes and metaclasses.

Boiling it down, this:

```
[[NSObject class] isMemberOfClass:[NSObject class]]
```

... correctly returns `NO` because the metaclass that contains information about `NSObject` is not itself an instance of `NSObject`. Conversely, this:

```
[[NSObject new] isMemberOfClass:[NSObject class]]
```

... would return `YES` because you've created an **instance** of `NSObject` rather than inspecting the metaclass. **The metaclass descends from `NSObject` but is not itself an instance of `NSObject`**.

So what exactly is it that you're trying to test? Whether a class descends from `NSObject`, without having an instance of that class? If so you probably need manually to walk the `isa` chain. E.g.

```
- (BOOL)class:(Class)someClass isSubclassOf:(Class)class
{
    while(someClass)
    {
        if(someClass == class) break;
        someClass = class_getSuperclass(someClass);
    }

    return !!someClass;
}
```

You should see:

```
[self class:[NSObject class] isSubclassOf:[NSObject class]] // YES
[self class:[NSProxy class] isSubclassOf:[NSObject class]]  // NO
```

If you don't mind the namespace implications, possibly even:

```
@interface NSObject (ObjectIndicator)
@end

@implementation NSObject (ObjectIndicator)
+ (void)someOldMethodOrOther {};
@end
```

And then:

```
[NSProxy respondsToSelector:@selector(someOldMethodOrOther)];
```

Comment: Thanks -- indeed I was mixing up classes and metaClasses. I needed to compare using someClass == [NSObject class]

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `Class` instances:

```
BOOL isNSObjectClass = aSuperClass == [NSObject class];
```